# How to place a Quarry in Tekkit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

Was wondering if anyone could explain to me how to properly place down a Quarry using Land Marks.

I think I know the basics:

1. Place down 3 Land marks in a triangle
2. Right-click the middle one to create a red square
3. Place the Quarry down next to the middle Land Mark

And sometimes this works. *However* what often happens is that the Land Marks just explodes and the Quarry gets no black and yellow frame at all.

What is the cause of this? How do I place down the Quarry properly so that this won't happen?

Answer (score 1):

It's more reliable to place four land marks in a square. Remember that the maximum quarry size is 64x64, so if your quarry is bigger than that it won't work. Once you've placed your land marks, right click one of them and if they've been placed successfully a red cuboid frame will appear. That will be the frame of your quarry. Next place the quarry down next to any of the land marks. The red frame should change to yellow and black stripes, and all the land marks except one will drop as items (one land mark won't drop, just hit it with your hand and you'll be able to pick it up again). After that, you'll have to supply your quarry with sufficient energy. Quarries can run at any speed up to 5 blocks per second, but a fair amount of power is needed to get them up to a speed at which they can run effectively. You can use either BuildCraft engines (you will need a minimum of three steam or two combustion to run the quarry at a good speed, redstone engines just aren't strong enough) or you can use IndustrialCraft electricity. If you're going to use IC power, you'll need an energy link. Place the energy link directly next to the quarry and connect your BatBox/MFE/MFSU to the energy link with the appropriate cable. Bear in mind that quarries use quite a lot of EU, so you will need a large power source. Sufficient energy is provided by:

- Nuclear reactors
- Two or more LV solar arrays
- Geothermal generators

You can use water/wind mills to provide power as well, but your quarry will run very slowly if you don't have loads of them. It is best to have the power coming from an MFE or an MFSU because they provide higher voltages and allow your quarry to run faster. Once power is provided to the quarry, wait a few seconds and an orange frame should be built along the yellow and black lines. When the frame is complete, a mining arm should extend down and start to mine blocks. Remember to hook up BuildCraft pipes to your quarry so it can put the mined blocks in a chest.

Comment: BuildCraft quarries use MJ (Buildcraft Energy) which is made with Engines not Generators

Comment: @JoethePerson But IC power is converted to MJ via the energy link. That's why you need an energy link with IC power but not with engines

Comment: oh I didn't see the part about the Energy Link.

Comment: Thanks, nice full answer. Goes a bit further than my question though, is related to the old version of Tekkit and doesn't include an important detail I discovered, so I added a shorter answer myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out the necessary procedure to place a Quarry. The important bit, which was not mentioned in the other answer here, is that the red beam rectangle must not be obstructed by anything. So here's the full list of steps to take.

1. Place first Land Mark where you want your Quarry
2. Place a Redstone Torch next to the Land Mark
   *This creates red beams, 64 blocks long, in all directions*
3. Place two more Land Marks *in* two of the beams to make a triangle
4. Return to Quarry spot, remove the Redstone Torch and right-click the Land Mark
   *This should create a red beam rectangle if you have placed the Land Marks correctly*
5. **Make sure the red rectangle beams does not go through any ground/trees/etc**
6. Place your Quarry next to the Land Mark (outside the red rectangle), with its backside pointed at the Land Mark. See diagram below.

I let the rectangle go through trees and hills before, but when I now have started to make sure the path is clear for the rectangle it seems to work consistently every time.

---

Q=Quarry, x=Land Mark

```
    |
    |
    x——————————
    Q
```